# Adding VPC Peering in CloudFormation across different regions

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am creating a VPC peering between 2 VPC's in different regions.For the VpcId for the peeringconnection setup I am trying to import the VPC ID from another stack that previously created the VPC. Here's my code:

```
VpcPeeringConnection:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection"
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${VpcStack}-vpcId
      PeerVpcId: !Ref PeerVPCId
      PeerRegion: !Ref PeerRegion
```

I get the following error

```
Template error: the attribute in Fn::ImportValue must not depend on any resources, imported values, or Fn::GetAZs
```

Comment: Did you export the VPC id as an output from other stack? More details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the `Fn::ImportValue` to retrieve a value from a stack in another region.

> You can't create cross-stack references across regions. You can use the intrinsic function Fn::ImportValue to import only values that have been exported within the same region.
>   [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)